# Android, issue in Speed control of RenderView for a game

Tags: android, render

I use this class to update the render view

```
public class AndroidFastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    AndroidGame game;
    Bitmap framebuffer;
    Thread renderThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    float speedRegulator= 100000009.9f;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    public AndroidFastRenderView(AndroidGame game, Bitmap framebuffer) {
        super(game);
        this.game = game;
        this.framebuffer = framebuffer;
        this.holder = getHolder();
    }

    public void resume() { 
        running = true;
        renderThread = new Thread(this);
        renderThread.start();         
    }      

    public void run() {
        Rect dstRect = new Rect();
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        while(running) {  
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;           

            float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) /speedRegulator;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            game.getCurrentScreen().update(deltaTime);
            game.getCurrentScreen().present(deltaTime);

            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.getClipBounds(dstRect);
            canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, dstRect, null);                           
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void pause() {                        
        running = false;                        
        while(true) {
            try {
                renderThread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // retry
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

The number:

```
float speedRegulator= 100000009.9f;
```

is the parameter that allow me to decrease and increase the speed of the player, unfortunately if I set this to float `speedRegulator= 1000000000.0f;` is too slow, and if leave `float speedRegulator= 100000009.9f;` is too fast.

How I could fix this? Why the speed change isn't gradual?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a gradual change because `1000000000.0f` is roughly ten times `100000009.9f`. If you're trying to get it a bit faster(say 10%), try something along the lines of `900000000`.